# Swap column names with row values in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, columnsorting

I am kind of stucked in a pretty simple task - at least what I thought.

Suppose you have a DataFrame with following shape (So the data frame is given)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col a": [0, 1, 2, 3, "name a"],
                   "col b": [0, 1, 2, 3, "name b"],
                   "col c": [0, 1, 2, 3, "name c"]})

    col a   col b   col c
0       0       0       0
1       1       1       1
2       2       2       2
3       3       3       3
4  name a  name b  name c
```

If I use the following command

```
df.columns=df.iloc[4]
```

the original header disappears. Any suggestion how to achieve my goal. Of course if it would be one sheet I could do it manually, however I have multiple sheets and this need to automatize it

Any kind of support is really appreciated
The result should be that way

```
  name  name  name 
0     0     0     0
1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3
4  col a  col b  col c
```

Answer (score 1):

Like in any case where you want to swap 2 values in a program, you need to use an intermediate variable.

You can let python do that for you by taking advantage of the `A, B = B, A` syntax:

```
df.columns, df.iloc[4] = df.iloc[4].to_list(), df.columns
```

output:

```
  name a name b name c
0      0      0      0
1      1      1      1
2      2      2      2
3      3      3      3
4  col a  col b  col c
```

##### ignoring first columns in the swap:

```
df = df.set_index(['col a', 'col b'])
df.columns, df.iloc[4] = df.iloc[4].to_list(), df.columns
df = df.reset_index()
```

output:

```
    col a   col b name c
0       0       0      0
1       1       1      1
2       2       2      2
3       3       3      3
4  name a  name b  col c
```

Comment: That needs to be done with the entire frame. Any suggestion on that? Is a one line possibe?

Comment: @SMS Can you update your example?

Comment: @SMS Well it depends on how you want to identify the columns to ignore. One simply way would be to set it temporarily as index, then swap, then reset index to columns

Answer (score 0):

It's important to use the `.rename` method from Pandas instead of just assigning new column names

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col a": [0, 1, 2, 3, "name"]})

col_name = df.columns.to_list()[0]
var_name = df.iloc[4].values[0]
df = df.rename(columns={col_name: var_name})
df.iloc[4, :] = col_name
```

result:

```
name
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   col a
```